# Codeigniter check unique value when editing form without using callback function

Tags: validation, codeigniter-2, unique, codeigniter

Codeigniter check unique value while editing form.

When edit the form it checks for current row, and it give username already exist. so how to avoid it.and don't check for current record.

So how can i pass id to is_unique function in CI_Form_Validation class function and add condition?

See my below code:

```
$this->custom_validation->set_rules('username','Username',
                    'trim|required|max_length[30]|is_unique[adminuser.username]');
```

Comment: can you provide us your all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put a unique validation only if value of that field is changed ie.

```
$old_value='old value';
if ($posted_value!=$old_value) {
  $this->custom_validation->set_rules('username','Username',
                    'trim|required|max_length[30]|is_unique[adminuser.username]');

} else {
  $this->custom_validation->set_rules('username','Username',
                    'trim|required|max_length[30]);
}
```